# Elasticsearch Sort by: element presence in the array and date

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I want to build a query on v5.6 where I find all books that:

- belong to a user or are marked as favourite by that user
- and then sort them by the fact that they are his **favourite first** and date desc.
  Book record would look like this

```
{
  title: "book1"
  users_favourite: ["1", "2"],
  userid: "1",
  date: timestamp
}
```

I have most of the query but I don't know how to put favourite books on top and sorted by date:

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 51,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "should" : [
        {
          "match" : {
            "users_favourite" : {
              "query" : "1",
              "operator" : "OR"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term" : {
            "userid" : {
              "value" : "1"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort" : [
    {
      "date" : {
        "order" : "desc",
        "missing" : "_last",
        "unmapped_type" : "string"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So the output would be: all users favourite books first, sorted by date
followed by books owned by that user also ordered by date.

| user's favourite | date |
| --- | --- |
| true | 2021 |
| true | 2020 |
| true | 2018 |
| false | 2021 |
| false | 2019 |
| false | 2017 |

Comment: 1. What is the mapping type for "users_favourite "?
2. Can the query search for multiple "users_favourite" or just one?
3. Can "users_favourite" be empty?

Comment: 1. users_favourite mapping is keyword   
2. I always query for one user   
3. yes users_favourite cab be empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution I would use is something like this

Regarding sorting:

```json
GET social_unique_flat_verified_guesses/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 51,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "users_favourite": {
              "query": "1",
              "operator": "OR"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "userid": {
              "value": "1"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "doc['users_favourite'].contains(params.users_favourite) ? 1 : 0",
          "params": {
            "users_favourite": "1"
          }
        },
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "date": {
        "order": "desc",
        "missing": "_last",
        "unmapped_type": "string"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This tells elastic to first score all matched (1 or 0) if the book is in the user's favorite, then by year.

Also I would change the should clause for the user favorite to this

```
"term": {
      "users_favourite": {
        "value": "1"
      }
    }
```

Keep in mind that if the "users_favourite" field can be empty, or if the query can search for multiple user favorites the query needs to be a bit different. So let me know and I'll edit it

Comment: Thanks @ron-serruya this solution works. One change I had to do was to remove value so the source is "doc['users_favourite'].contains(params.users_favourite) ? 1 : 0"

Comment: @rPawel Yeah you are right, .value takes the first index instead of the entire list